# Dart: How to return Future<void>

Tags: android, asynchronous, flutter, future

How can I return `Future<void>` ?

```
   Future<void> deleteAll(List stuff){
       stuff.forEach( s => delete(s));   //How do I return Future<void> when loop and all delete Operation are finished?
   }

   Future<void> delete(Stuff s) async {
      ....
      file.writeAsString(jsonEncode(...));
   }
```

How do I return `Future<void>` when the `forEach` loop and all delete Operations are finished?

Comment: @pascal I don't think `Giovanni Terlingen` answer is correct. See these example [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/6b250102358433a6edb7ec78c9689803)

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't need to return anything manually, since an `async` function will only return when the function is actually done, but it depends on how/if you wait for invocations you do in this function.

Looking at your examples you are missing the `async` keyword, which means you need to write the following instead:

```
Future<void> deleteAll(List stuff) async {
    stuff.forEach( s => delete(s));
}

Future<void> delete(Stuff s) async {
   ....
   await file.writeAsString(jsonEncode(...));
}
```

When using `Future<void>` there is no need to explicitly return anything, since `void` is nothing, as the name implies.

Also make sure you call `deleteAll` and `writeAsString()` using `await`.

*Note: To wait for all `delete`/`foreach` invocations to complete, see below answer for more details. In short you will need to put all `delete` invocations in a `Future.wait` for that.*

Comment: I want to get notified, when deleteAll and all delete calls are finished, so that I can use delteAll().then(() => refreshUI()). What would be the correct strategy for that?

Comment: delete() is an async function. I forgot to add the async keyword in the code snippet. The implementation of delete()  is using getApplicationsDIrectory() which is also an async function.

Comment: This is not correct. try adding `print("deleteAll")` after `stuff.forEach...`. And  add `print("delete")` after `file.writeAs....`. You will see `deleteAll` printed before printing all `delete`.

Comment: So you can see `forEach`  only called `delete` function asyncronoslly. it won't wait for completion of `delete` method

Comment: And also don't forget to add `await file.writeAsString`

Answer (score 4):

You can't  do that with `forEach`.

But you can use `Future.wait` and `.map` like this

```
Future<void> deleteAll(List stuff) {
  return Future.wait(stuff.map((s) => delete(s)));
}

Future<void> delete(Stuff s) async{
  ....
  await file.writeAsString(jsonEncode(...));
}
```

**When to use `async` keyword:**

You can use `async` when your function uses `await` keyword inside.

**So when to use `await` keyword:**

1. when you want to get the result from an asynchronous function and want do some logic on the result

```
Future<int> fetchCountAndValidate() asycn{
  final result = await fetchCountFromServer();
  if(result == null)
    return 0;
  else
   return result;
}
```

2. When you want to call multiple asynchronous function

```
Future<int> fetchTotalCount() asycn{
  final result1 = await fetchCount1FromServer();
  final result2 = await fetchCount2FromServer();
  return result1 + result2;
}
```

**When you don't need `async` or `await`:**

1. When you just calling another asynchronous function

```
Future<int> getCount(){
  //some synchronous logic
  final requestBody = {
    "countFor": "..."
  };
  return fetchCountFromServer(requestBody); //this is an asynchronous function which returns `Future<int>`
}
```

2. For some rare cases we doesn't care about the completion of asynchronous function

```
void sendLogoutSignal(){
  http.post(url, {"username" : "id0001"});
}
```

Comment: For those cases where we don't care about completion, wrap the call in `unawaited()`. https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/unawaited_futures